# setInterval is getting called only on some action on the screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am loading an URL and if the URL is invalid, as soon as the page loads, I want to display an error message.

I am setting interval of 1second on the function that validates the URL.But, message is getting displayed only if I click on empty screen.

Please help me in loading the message as soon as the URL loads.

Here is my code :

```
timer = setInterval(function() {
    $scope.ValidateUrl();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Use the $interval service as it looks like a digest cycle issue

Comment: where did you define your $scope variable?

Comment: `$scope.$apply(function(){ return $scope.ValidateUrl() });` i guess you need to tell the angular to check there is the change in the scope. So if you do use a native js method inside angular js app angular doesn't track the changes applied by it, you have to tell angular to see with as suggested above.

Comment: What do you mean by _invalid_? Catch the HTTP error on load, and display the error message accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to tell the angular to check there is the change in the scope. So if you do use a native js method inside angular js app angular doesn't track the changes applied by it.

You have to tell angular to track the changes in the current scope via `$apply(fn)`:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){ 
     return $scope.ValidateUrl();
});
```

Comment: `$interval` does it, then why should we go for `$apply` manually?

Comment: @pankajparkar i guess you just saw the snippet only not the posted lines.

Comment: my concern is angular does provide `$interval` which does work as same as `setInterval` & also run digest cycle, then why we are considering to run `digest` cycle manually?

Comment: @pankajparkar no doubt you are right. but it was just another way of doing that's it. i posted it because you already posted the same as you are saying so duplicacy was the concern for me.

Comment: but I personally feel like you don't need to run digest cycle manually..it considered as bad pattern https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns

Answer (score 0):

Looks like digest cycle is not running because you are using javascript function `setInterval`, You should use `$interval`, wrap function in `$interval` will run digest cycle after running a function.

**Code**

```
timer = $interval(function() {
    $scope.ValidateUrl();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: @Pooja does my answer helpful to you?